# Looking for a decent jquery slider that features methods to trigger sliding via code

Tags: jquery, slider

Any recommendations for a decent query slider that allows you to call functions via code to allow you to navigate to panels. i.e. `$('#mySlider').gotoPanel(3);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I  am a big fan of jquery cycle for its flexibility and use of use.
Per your question, `$('#div').cycle(3);` goes to slide 2.

Answer (score 1):

The [Galleria](http://galleria.aino.se/) jQuery plugin can do this. Use `.show(index)`.

> Shows the image specified as index. You can call this method anytime and the image will be placed in a transition queue.

http://galleria.aino.se/docs/1.2/api/methods/#show-index

---

[jCarousel](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/) also supports this via the `.scroll(index)` method. Use `.data('jcarousel')` to [access the instance directly](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/#Accessing-The-Jcarousel-Instance):

```
$("#mycarousel").data('jcarousel').scroll(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look a jquery tools scrollable and methode seekTo(index, speed)